# Burninate or disambiguiate the [data] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Looking through [data](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/data) (x70), there's a lot of ambiguity:

- data transmission
- data encryption
- data recovery
- data saving
- data in Excel
- data editing

So, unless somebody wants to retag these manually, I'd nuke it. Otherwise we should come up with appropriate replacements:

- [data-transmission](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/data-transmission), a new tag
- [data-encryption](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/data-encryption), possibly related to [encryption](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/encryption)
- [data-recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery), which already exists (x429)
- [data-processing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/data-processing), possibly related to [text-editing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/text-editing)

Any other ideas?

Comment: The new tags are useless. What else are you going to transfer, encrypt, or process?

Comment: True of course. But if nobody wants to nuke them..? ;)

Comment: @DanielBeck I partially disagree. "Data recovery" and the like are known terms. Plain "recovery" doesn't necessary tell you as much. Plus, if you have a "data" tag, clearly people are trying to use the word "data", so including it in the better tags so that they will come up in the suggested tags pop-up is potentially a good idea.

Comment: @AnnaLear I think the best idea would be to add synonyms to already existing tags where possible and otherwise remove the tag from those questions that are reasonably explained by their other tags already. I still think that `data-transmission` is not a particularly good tag, but it's better than just `data` or `transmission`.

Comment: @Anna you picked the one tag there that already existed. It won't work as nicely if you try that e.g. With encryption or processing.

Comment: @DanielBeck Sorry, I should've been more clear. That's why I said I partially disagree. :) I like slhck's suggestion of using synonyms. I also don't think that tags like "processing" would be useful - it's not clear what it means right away, IMHO. Others, like "encryption", would work just fine on their own, though.

Answer (score 0):

The tag does carry meaning for each question it's used on, even though it's different meaning depending on which question you're looking at, so I don't think just deleting it outright would be appropriate.

Because it does change meaning depending on the question, it is a good candidate for disambiguation: questions about transmitting data should be retagged with [data-transfer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/data-transfer), questions about recovering data with [data-recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery), etc. Questions that are closed and cannot be edited and reopened can just be deleted without retagging. Questions that should've been closed but weren't don't need to be retagged either and should be closed instead.

Think of it as a clean-up on a fairly small scale. :)

Once this is done, we can talk about possibly blacklisting the generic [data](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/data) tag if it keeps coming back.

Comment: [data-startrek]...

Comment: Of course you're right. I think someone else should quickly look through the questions and try to come up with a few more tag ideas except for the ones I've now added to my question. I could retag them later that day.

Comment: What else would we be transferring, encrypting, or recovering? These terms stand alone without the data prefix, at least as far as on topic questions are concerned. So we already have all the tags for disambiguation, and the data tag is simply redundant.